# I want to upload to S3 with django model filefield without django-storages

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a REST API with Django Rest Framework which includes upload files. I want to upload files to S3 with some dynamically created key(which I create based on some data I receive). However, Django FileField in my models needs a path to upload. If I do not provide a path it holds in memory and later uploads them to the main folder of the server. I want the default file storage to be S3. All the results I searched I got results using `django-storages` library only. Is it possible to implement this using `boto3` only?